# flutter scrollable position

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, scrollable

I was working with Scrollable and Viewport widget in flutter and i confused to realize where or how Scrollable widget notified when it's ScrollPosition.pixels change via users dragging (my problem is when user touched the screen and now move its touch to update the dragging offset).
in my exploration i found that this method stack invoke while a user move his touch:

```
Scrollable::_handleUpdate ->
ScrollDragController::update ->
ScrollPositionWithSingleContext::applyUserOffset ->
ScrollPositionWithSingleContext::setPixels ->
ScrollPosition::setPixels ->
```

but in ScrollPosition::setPixels i see no mechanism to notify Scrollable widget.
because in Scrollable widget there is not any addListener method to listen ScrollController or ScrollPosition directly.
now my final question is "how Scrollable widget notified with new position to rebuild itself and expose new position to viewport ?"

am i missing something ?

sorry for my poor English .

Comment: check for example `_RenderSingleChildViewport` class, here `offset` is passed to the constructor and `addListener` is called on it

Comment: @pskink  oooh , i see. i forgotted to check the render object of viewports. even though i don't know this class you named but it made me to check the RenderViewport class . and i saw the offset.addListener in attach method. thanks, solution was in render objects

Comment: notice that you don't need `Viewport` and its `RenderViewport` - some time ago I made a custom `Scrollable` that uses `ViewportOffset` to animate scrolled stuff - you can check two examples in the comment and see how it works, code here: https://gist.github.com/pskink/5fd59d240beb8dd9d780f978e5c76b3c#file-sized_content_scrollable-dart-L290